# Pre-populating list in Survey123 using SQL Server column

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, sql-server, arcgis-survey123

What I currently have is a Survey which enters the data collected from the survey in a SQL Server table, I'd like for one of those columns in that table to become the choices in another survey.

If this is not possible, are there any other tools I can use to accomplish this using ArcGIS?

Comment: Survey123 is designed to work offline (ie, without a network connection).  So anything that requires database access is not possible (apart from actually submitting the survey, which of course requires a network connection).  This is a bit simplified.  Javascript can be used to work around some of these limitations.

Comment: Is there an article you can point me to that would show me how I can use scripts to manipulate a Survey123 project?

Comment: I've not heard of anybody using javascript to manage the choices in a Survey123 list, so I don't think that's possible.  And I've never used javascript in a survey myself, so I don't understand how it works.  But I've seen various posts about it here and there for various different purposes.  You can find some of these at:  https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+in+survey123